# git stash -how to switch between uncommitted versions

Tags: git, git-stash

**[git newbie here]**

Say I'm working on a new file and I'm writing the following story:

```
Version1: A guy walks into a bar
          [here I tell my story]
```

At this point I like what I wrote but I wish to make some changes, so I stash my changes like this:

```
$git stash save -u 'version1: a guy walks'
```

I get the following message:

```
Saved working directory and index state On dev_story: version1: a guy walks
```

Next, I make a change:

```
Version2: A nice dude walks into a bar
          [here I tell a slighly different story]
```

and stash it again:

```
$git stash save -u 'version2: a dude walks'
```

received message:

```
Saved working directory and index state On dev_story: version2: a dude  walks
```

Checking my stash list I see:

```
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: On dev_story: version2: a dude walks
stash@{1}: On dev_story: version1: a guy walks
```

I wish to show my work to a friend and debate version1 vs version2.

when I try to apply stash@{0} it doesn't show 'a guy walks...'
what I have tried:

```
$ git stash show stash@{0}  //new line no error

$ git stash apply stash@{0} 

test/story.txt already exists, no checkout
error: could not restore untracked files from stash
```

Comment: Why do you want to `stash` instead `commiting` those changes?

Comment: there are few versions and I dont want to commit yet.

Comment: [Commits can always be undone, amended, merged, diffed, and reordered](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). In a lot of ways this winds up being easier than the stash, and they're skills you'll need anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $ git stash show stash@{0}  //new line no error

Git showed you nothing here because your file was untracked. `git stash show` will not show you untracked files unless you ask with `-u`.

```
$ git stash show -u stash@{0}
test/story.txt | 1 +
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

$ git stash show -u -p stash@{0}
diff --git a/test/story.txt b/test/story.txt
new file mode 100644
index 0000000..f5d91d3
--- /dev/null
+++ b/test/story.txt
@@ -0,0 +1 @@
+A nice dude walks into a bar
```

---

> ```
> $ git stash apply stash@{0} 
>
> test/story.txt already exists, no checkout
> error: could not restore untracked files from stash
> ```

You already had a test/story.txt file with changes. Because your stashed change *creates a new file*, git is protecting you from it overwriting the existing test/story.txt.

---

See [Stashing and Cleaning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) for more about the stash.

In general, I find it quite easy for the stash to get messy and to forget what's in there or what it applies to. Its useful to stash away changes for just a moment. For anything longer, I would recommend using commits and branches.

If you need to save some unfinished work, make a commit and log it as a "wip" (work in progress). Then [amend the commit later (see Changing the Last Commit](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). If you want to have two different versions, make a branch; that's what they're good at. Branches are very cheap.